# Android studio cant reach ADB server

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, adb

android studio doesn't recognize my phone, but it's was just recently.
before it was working okay.
Here's it what the event log says:

```
23:15   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

23:15   * daemon started successfully

23:15   Sending Tracking request failed!

23:15   Adb connection Error:Connection reset by peer

23:15   Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
```

I didn't do nothing, this problem started suddenly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating "Android SDK Platform-Tools" to 30.0.4 solved the problem
[path to SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwrSo.png)

Comment: It was probably something else, as I am currently having that problem with version 31.0.0 of the tools.

Answer (score 11):

1-file ->  2-setting ->  -3Build, Execution, Deployment -> 4-Debugger -> **untick "Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging"**

Comment: Corresponding defect in Google's bug tracker: [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217251994](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217251994)

Comment: may be this will disable connexion for wifi debug ?

Comment: This worked, I am using latest Android Studio Flamingo  | 2022.2.1 Patch 2. 

Thanks!

Comment: OMG, this workaround is still the only solution that works for me even if I am using the very latest version of Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023
Why is this bug not yet fixed? Anyway, thanks for the fix

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in android studio,now it's working.